# Is there a way to change and display the value of radio buttons with a checkbox click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to advance my understanding in JavaScript and I'm looking to recreate the price generator on this page [here](https://www.redirecthealth.com/self-employed-health/) (you have to scroll down a tad, it'll say "Let's Get Started"). I can't figure out how to change the display prices at the top when either of the two checkboxes are clicked. Here is the codepen I currently have: [code](https://codepen.io/lyss-js/pen/xxERrpe). Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    <div class="flex justify-between items-start flex-wrap -m-16">
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-16 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 flex justify-center items-center">
            <div class="flex-grow flex-shrink">
                <h4 class="text-24 text-center font-semibold">iEverydayCARE™ with Hospitalization</h4> 
                <ul class="list-reset text-center mt-32 max-w-260 mx-auto">
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">National Direct Primary Care
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">24-Hour Concierge
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Lab Benefits
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Prescription Drug Program
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Chiropractic Office Visits
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Vision, Dental &amp; Mental Health Discounts
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Referral and Care Navigation
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Open Network
                        <!---->
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">Medical Cost Share<sup>1</sup>
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">$3000 Annual out-of-pocket Maximum Per Family<sup>*/†</sup>
                    </li>
                    <li class="pb-8 whitespace-pre-line">$1000 per condition member responsibility<sup>*</sup>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 p-16 flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 text-gray-dark">
            <div>
                <div class="bg-white rounded-18 p-16 relative z-1">
                    <ul class="list-reset text-16 font-bold flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 flex flex-col justify-between">
                        <li>
                            <div class="mb-18 text-center flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                                <h4 class="flex justify-center items-center leading-none text-blue-light"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-24 md:text-48 -ml-14 md:-ml-20">$</span> <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 h1_xl2" id="price">319</span></h4> 
                                <p class="text-18 font-normal">PER MONTH</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="mb-8">
                                <label class="check_box">
                                    <input type="radio" id="m" name="radio" value="m" onclick="changeMyself()">
                                    <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16 text-blue-light"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself</span>  <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="myselfSmoke">$319/mo.</span>
                                    </div> <span class="radiomark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="mb-8">
                                <label class="check_box">
                                    <input type="radio" id="ms" name="radio" value="ms" onclick="changeMS()">
                                    <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Spouse</span>  <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="msSmoke">$639/mo.</span>
                                    </div> <span class="radiomark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="mb-8">
                                <label class="check_box">
                                    <input type="radio" id="mc" name="radio" value="mc" onclick="changeMC()">
                                    <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Children</span>  <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mcSmoke">$639/mo.</span>
                                    </div> <span class="radiomark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mb-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                            <div class="mb-8">
                                <label class="check_box">
                                    <input type="radio" id="mf" name="radio" value="mf" onclick="changeMF()">
                                    <div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap text-14 sm:text-16"><span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 text-12 sm:text-16">Myself + Family</span>  <span class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 ml-4" id="mfSmoke">$899/mo.</span>
                                    </div> <span class="radiomark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="my-4 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 p-8 -mx-8 rounded-6 bg-blue-light">
                            <label class="check_box">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="areYouASmoker" id="smoker" onclick="smoker()">
                                <div class="text-white">
                                    <p class="text-14 leading-none text-center mr-32 md:mr-0">Yes. A member uses tobacco.</p>
                                    <p class="text-12 leading-none font-normal text-center mr-32">($75 surcharge)</p>
                                </div> <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-gray-lightest rounded-18 px-16 pb-16 pt-48 -mt-32">
                    <label class="check_box">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sayNoToPlus" class="bg-white" id="sayNoToPlus" onclick="sayNoToPlus()">
                        <div>
                            <p class="leading-thin text-14 text-center mr-24">I have my own
                                <br>Medical Cost Share / Insurance</p>
                        </div> <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-16">
        <!---->
        <p class="text-16 mb-16 max-w-500 mx-auto text-left md:text-center">Members age 65 and over are not eligible for Medical Cost Share. Tobacco users will incur an extra $75 surcharge</p>
        <div class="max-w-330 mx-auto"><a href="/uploads/i_Everyday_CARE_with_Hospitalization_88f13de61a.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="btn_sqr_trans_white block mt-16 text-center">Benefit Summary</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function changeMyself() {
  var myself = document.getElementById('m').checked;

  if (myself === true) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '319';
  }
}
function changeMS() {
var myself_spouse = document.getElementById('ms').checked;

  if (myself_spouse === true) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '639';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '394';
  }
}
function changeMC() {
var myself_children = document.getElementById('mc').checked;

  if (myself_children === true) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '639';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '394';
  }
}

function changeMF() {
var myself_family = document.getElementById('mf').checked;

  if (myself_family === true) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '899';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = '394';
  }
}

function smoker() {
  var smoker = document.getElementById('smoker').checked;
  if (smoker === true) {
    document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$394/mo.';
    document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$974/mo.';
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
}

function sayNoToPlus() {
  var sayNoToPlus = document.getElementById('sayNoToPlus').checked;
  if (sayNoToPlus === true) {
    document.getElementById('smoker').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$125/mo.';
    document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$240/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$250/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$365/mo.';
    var changeMF = document.getElementById('mf').value;
    changeMF = '1000';
    console.log(changeMF);
    var myself = document.getElementById('m').checked;
    console.log(myself);
    if (myself === false){
      document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = changeMF;
    }
  }
  
   else {
  document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
}
```

Comment: You have hampered yourself through the structure of your code. You should have a `setPrice()` function that has the sole responsibility of changing that number at the top. That would make it easy then, don't you think?

Comment: @RandyCasburn my problem is changing the price when one of the other two are selected

Comment: Yes, I understand. With your current code, everywhere you want to effect that price, you must write code to change it. That means the several places you do it already (duplicated) and the two places you desire it to be done. So your choices are write the same code you've written several times already, or consolidate that price change code into a single function - perhaps called `setPrice()`. You'll also need to determine which radio button is checked so you know which hard-coded price to use.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks, although i still haven't figured it out

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!! Woo!!

```
function setPrice() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
  var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;
}

function setSmokerPrice() {
  var smoker = document.getElementById('smoker').checked;
    if (smoker === true) {
      document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$394/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$974/mo.';

    document.getElementById('m').value = '394';
    document.getElementById('ms').value = '714';
    document.getElementById('mc').value = '714';
    document.getElementById('mf').value = '974';

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
    var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;
  }
  else {
         document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
}

function setMedicalSharePrice() {
 var medicalShare = document.getElementById('sayNoToPlus').checked;
 if (medicalShare === true) {
       document.getElementById('smoker').disabled = true;

    document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$125/mo.';
    document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$240/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$240/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$365/mo.';
  
  document.getElementById('m').value = '125';
  document.getElementById('ms').value = '240';
  document.getElementById('mc').value = '240';
  document.getElementById('mf').value = '365';
  
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");
  var selected = Array.from(radios).find(radio => radio.checked);
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = selected.value;
 }
    else {
          document.getElementById('smoker').disabled = false;

         document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
      document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
}


function smoker() {
  var smoker = document.getElementById('smoker').checked;
  if (smoker === true) {
    document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$394/mo.';
    document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$714/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$974/mo.';
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById('myselfSmoke').innerHTML = '$319/mo.';
      document.getElementById('msSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mcSmoke').innerHTML = '$639/mo.';
    document.getElementById('mfSmoke').innerHTML = '$899/mo.';
  }
}
```